# Tenho um dataframe de datas/horas inicio e final, como faço pra separar para datas / hora inicio / hora final no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Na base de dados eu tenho um relatorio que contem:

```
INICIO              FINAL
20/07/2021 09:17    20/07/2021 09:25
20/07/2021 09:17    20/07/2021 09:25
20/07/2021 09:17    20/07/2021 09:25
20/07/2021 09:28    20/07/2021 09:33
```

Preciso transformar em isso:

```
DATA       HORA INICIO  HORA FINAL
20/07/2021  09:17:10    09:25:17
20/07/2021  09:17:10    09:25:17
20/07/2021  09:17:10    09:25:17
...
```

fiz um codigo tentando duas funções

```
 import pandas as pd
 
 relatorio = pd.read_csv('relatorio.csv', encoding='latin1', sep=';')

 datas_df = relatorio[['INICIO','FINAL']]

 for dhi in datas_df['INICIO']:
    data, hora_inicio = dhi.split(' ')
    datas_df['DATA'] = data
    datas_df['HORA INICIO'] = hora_inicio
    relatorio.append(datas_df['DATA'])
    relatorio.append(datas_df['HORA INICIO'])

 for dhf in datas_df['FINAL']:
    data_f, hora_final = dhf.split(' ')
    datas_df['HORA FINAL'] = hora_final
    relatorio.insert(loc=2, column='HORA FINAL', value=datas_df['HORA FINAL'])
```

Dessa forma o 1º for da erro pois não existe o 'DATA', e no 2º for não da erro, mas só pega o ultimo valor da data e hora.

Fiz com esses **2 for** para citar exemplos de métodos que eu tentei.

Conseguem ajudar? Acho que é alguma coisa no sentido do loop for né?

Answer (score 3):

Apenas use o constructor do [pandas.DataFrame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) combinado com as propriedades [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) para acessar os valores datetime das series:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  ["20/07/2021 09:17:10", "20/07/2021 09:25:17"],
  ["20/07/2021 09:17:10", "20/07/2021 09:25:17"],
  ["20/07/2021 09:17:10", "20/07/2021 09:25:17"],
  ["20/07/2021 09:28:16", "20/07/2021 09:33:27"],
], columns=['INICIO', 'FIM'], dtype='datetime64[ns]');

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "DATA": df['INICIO'].dt.date,
  "HORA INICIO": df['INICIO'].dt.time,
  "HORA FIM": df['FIM'].dt.time,  
})

print(df2)
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Times#main.py)</sup>

```
         DATA HORA INICIO  HORA FIM
0  2021-07-20    09:17:10  09:25:17
1  2021-07-20    09:17:10  09:25:17
2  2021-07-20    09:17:10  09:25:17
3  2021-07-20    09:28:16  09:33:27
```

No caso fora usados [`pandas.Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) e [`pandas.Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html#)

Comment: Obrigado, muito útil!

Comment: @HD13sel, aqui no Stack Overflow se diz obrigado votando nas publicações. Veja: [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa forma:

```
datas_df = relatorio[['INICIO','FINAL']]
datas = []
horas_i = []
horas_f = []
for dhi in datas_df['INICIO']:
    data, hora_inicio = dhi.split(' ')
    datas.append(data)
    horas_i.append(hora_inicio)
for dhf in datas_df['FINAL']:
    data_f, hora_final = dhf.split(' ')
    horas_f.append(hora_final)
datas_df['DATA'] = datas
datas_df['HORA INICIO'] = horas_i
datas_df['HORA FINAL'] = horas_f
datas_df = datas_df.drop(columns=['INICIO', 'FINAL'])
display(datas_df)

    DATA    HORA INICIO HORA FINAL
0   20/07/2021  09:17:10    09:25:17
1   20/07/2021  09:17:10    09:25:17
2   20/07/2021  09:17:10    09:25:17
3   20/07/2021  09:28:16    09:33:27
4   20/07/2021  09:28:16    09:33:27
```

Se voces quiserem me dar algumas dicas. Sempre bem vindo!